# Post Request as Media in MMS

Tags: python, image, flask, twilio, webserver

I wrote a python program that gets a photo from a webserver. The photo is obtained by sending a POST request to my URL (the returned photo depends on data of POST request):

```
myobj = {'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [1,2,3,6]}

x = requests.post('http://cainevisualizer.azurewebsites.net/plot.png', data=myobj)
```

`x` is a `requests.Response` object with methods giving its content, status code, the response url, the text (in unicode) etc (see all methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp). However, it appears that, in order to send a text message of an image in Twilio, Message().media requires the URL of the image.

```
message = Message()
message.media(myURL)
```

Again, the webserver (in Flask) returns an image after a post request rather than returning a unique url to the image. Is there an API or some other way to convert a MIME image into a unique url? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you just get the image URL from the webserver. Otherwise, you will need to push the image to a server to host the image and provide Twilio that URL.

Comment: the webserver is setup such that you must provide a json in the body of the POST request... so there's not really a single URL you use to get the image—you need a full post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my own question. So, I changed the webserver that hosts the photo to now accept `GET` requests. I then pass my parameters to and send a GET request to the webserver. See the `GET` request as follows:

```
import requests

data = {'x[]': [1,2,3,4], 'y[]': [4,5,6,7]}
response = requests.get('http://cainevisualizer.azurewebsites.net/plot.png', params=data)
url = response.url
```

This request passes the parameters in the `data` dictionary as a single URL to the webserver. In this case, the `GET` request is encoded as a url and passes [1,2,3,4] and [4,5,6,7] as query parameters. This is instead of sending the information in the `GET` request as part of the body of the request (or as part of anything BUT the url itself)
I now use the `request.args.getlist('x[]')` and `request.args.getlist('y[]')` function in the webserver to to get the information from this `GET` request... it looks something like this

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/plot.png', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def plot():
    xs = request.args.getlist('x[]')
    ys = request.args.getlist('y[]')
```